# HTML Button redirects pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, redirect

I have the following button:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <button onclick="assign_all()" class="btn btn-default">Vælg alle</button>
</div>
```

Now this calls a JavaScript function called `assign_all`

This works fine however when it is done executing the JavaScript it simply tries to load a page. Which is fairly odd (its like if you click on an `A` tag)

As you can see below nothing in my javaScript indicates that it should reload / load a page:

```
function assign_all() {

    var info = [];
    var i = 0;
    $('.user_list').each(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('show')) {
            info[i] = $(this).find('.user_id').val();
            i++;
        }
    })
}
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's because the default `button` element's `type` attribute is set to `submit`. Your button element is attempting to submit a form. Simply give it a `type` of `button`:

```
<button onclick="assign_all()" class="btn btn-default" type="button">...</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add type="button" to your button tag. it must solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

you can do this also

```
<button onclick="assign_all();return false;" class="btn btn-default">Vælg alle</button>
```